# Migrating website content, need to test using Selenium/Python

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, python

We are working on a large project which involves LOTS of content being migrated to a new version of a website. I would like to be able to test the content on a page from the old site, with the same content on the new site, to ensure it all migrated properly (verifying elements/pictures/links are present etc.).

> *I've been using Selenium tests written in Python for all of my web-testing thus-far, but this task is a bit out of my league. Can I open and test two pages at once?*

Answer (score 5):

Do you need Selenium for this task?  If you have an existing suite of Selenium tests, you can run them against the new site to verify the functionality is working, but in general Selenium is not the best tool for validating look and feel, or massive amounts of content.

There are several link checker tools that will crawl all of the links and download all the images on your site and ensure they aren't broken.  In addition, you can simply diff the folders from the old site and the new site and ensuring all of the files are there where you expect them to be.

You can probably visually spot check the content as well, opening the same pages from the old site vs new site on monitors side by side.

Comment: I don't necessarily NEED Selenium, but the idea is to automate the process, as there is a ton of content. I'm sure we will be doing some visual spot checking, but there is so much stuff to check that it would be nice to use a tool to speed up the process. I'm looking into Google QualityBots right now, any experience with that?

Comment: What exactly is the goal of the testing you want to do?  What would you envision the automated test cases to look like that would do some comparison of the old page vs the migrated page?  When you say migrating, are you talking about the exact same content, migrated to a new server, or infrastructure?  Or are you talking about some other kind of migration where the CSS in the new site has changed and the look and feel are different?

Comment: It's basically a website refresh/face-lift. The content is the exact same, except it now has the new look of the new site. I'm looking to verify that all elements from the content on the old site, are present within the new site. After doing lots of research, it's looking like it might have to be a manual thing :(

Comment: If the html pages have not changed, and the changes were to CSS files, then you could probably diff the html files to ensure things still exist, but any changes to the style could impact whether the elements are displayed, or displayed correctly and will require some manual checking.

Answer (score 0):

As others say, Selenium is mostly oriented to behavior and such. Testing look and feel, while possible, is quite tough. Considering the coding, debugging and maintenance time, it'd be way cheaper to just get 2 or 3 people, 2 monitors each, and start looking around.

That said, as far as I remember, to open and navigate 2 pages at once, you could just create 2 webdriver elements and use them separately.
Such as:

```
drv = webdriver.Firefox()
drv.get("http://google.com")
other_drv = webdriver.Firefox()
other_drv.get("http://altavista.com")
```